# Why am I required to provide two option arguments when I only declared one option parameter?

Tags: f#

Why am I required to provide two option arguments when I only declared one option parameter?

**I declared the following type:**

```
type MiddleName =    MiddleName of string option
```

**To make the compiler happy I have to provide the Some case value twice:**

```
let middleName = Some <| MiddleName (Some "Kevin")
```

**Note:** I expect to provide the Some case value only once.

**Hence, I thought I should do this:**

```
let middleName = MiddleName (Some "Kevin")
```

Am I even doing this right?
Hence, a middle name should be optional and as a result, I am trying to model that.

**Appendix:**

```
type FirstName =     FirstName  of string
type LastName  =     LastName   of string
type MiddleName =    MiddleName of string option
type MaidenName =    MaidenName of string option
type Email =         Email      of string
type Phone =         Phone      of string

type Name = {
    FirstName:FirstName
    LastName:LastName
    MiddleName:MiddleName option
    MaidenName:MaidenName option
}

let someName = {
    FirstName=FirstName "Scott"
    LastName= LastName "Nimrod"
    MiddleName = Some <| MiddleName (Some "Kevin")
    MaidenName = None
```

}

Comment: How is `middleName` used? You can certainly do `let middleName = MiddleName (Some "Kevin")` so it looks like some other part of the code expects a `MiddleName option` somewhere?

Comment: As @Lee says, this is fine. You can see it works in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ivgH0r). I think you need to add some more context.

Comment: I added an appendix to my question.

Comment: There's still not sufficient code to reproduce this. You'd need to provide the definition of whatever your record type is. I'm going to guess you've defined `MiddleName` member with type `MiddleName option`, though.

Comment: Yes. I defined it as you guessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared a `MiddleName` type is an optional string, but you've also declared your `MiddleName` member as optional itself. So you have an optional `MiddleName` that contains an optional string.

One of those `optional` suffixes is not required. Note this also applies for `MaidenName` too.

You can either remove the option from the members like this (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a4kHuj)):

```
type Name = 
    { FirstName : FirstName
      LastName : LastName
      MiddleName : MiddleName
      MaidenName : MaidenName }

let someName = 
    { FirstName = FirstName "Scott"
      LastName = LastName "Nimrod"
      MiddleName = MiddleName (Some "Kevin")
      MaidenName = MaidenName None }
```

Or from the `MiddleName` / `MaidenName` types like this (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xosr6t)):

```
type MiddleName = MiddleName of string
type MaidenName = MaidenName of string

type Name = 
    { FirstName : FirstName
      LastName : LastName
      MiddleName : MiddleName option
      MaidenName : MaidenName option }

let someName = 
    { FirstName = FirstName "Scott"
      LastName = LastName "Nimrod"
      MiddleName = Some (MiddleName "Kevin")
      MaidenName = None }
```